# VHDL prog to implement 8to1 mux using 4to1 (structural modelling)

Tags: syntax, vhdl, mux

I am a student and have just started learning vhdl. So I need someone to point me in right direction. This is what i have done so far:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY MUX81 IS
PORT(
A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
S : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
Z : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END MUX81;
ARCHITECTURE struc OF MUX81 IS
SIGNAL Z1,Z2:STD_LOGIC;
COMPONENT mux41 is
PORT(A,B,C,D,S0,S1:IN STD_LOGIC;Q:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;
COMPONENT mux21 is
PORT(M,N,S2:IN STD_LOGIC;O:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;
for M1,M2:mux41
    use entity work.mux41(struc1);
for M3:mux21
    use entity work.mux21(arc);
signal Z1,Z2: std_logic;
BEGIN
M1 : mux41 PORT MAP(A(0),A(1),A(2),A(3),S(0),S(1),Z1);
M2 : mux41 PORT MAP(A(4),A(5),A(6),A(7),S(0),S(1),Z2);
M3 : mux21 PORT MAP(Z1,Z2,S(2),O);
END struc;
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY mux41 IS
PORT(
A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
S : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
Z : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END mux41;
ARCHITECTURE struc1 OF mux41 IS
component and3 is
(a,b,c : in std_logic;d : out std_logic);
end component;
component or4 is
(a,b,c,d : in std_logic;e : out std_logic);
end component;
for A1,A2,A3,A4:and3
    use entity work.and3(arc3);
for OR1:or4
    use entity work.or4(arc2);
signal s1,s2,s3,s4 : std_logic;
begin
A1 : and3 port map(A(0),not S(0),not S(1),s1);
A2 : and3 port map(A(1),not S(0),S(1),s2);
A3 : and3 port map(A(2),S(0),not S(1),s3);
A4 : and3 port map(A(3),S(0),S(1),s4);  
OR1 : or4 port map (s1,s2,s3,s4,Z);
end struc1; 
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity mux21 is
port(a,b,s : in bit;
c : out bit);
end mux21;
architecture arc of mux21 is 
signal O1,O2:std_logic;
component and3 is
(a,b,c : in std_logic;d : out std_logic);
end component;
component  or2 is
(a,b : in std_logic;c : out std_logic);   
end component;
for A5,A6:and3
    use entity work.and3(arc3);
for O1:or2
    use entity work.or2(arc1);
begin
A5 : and3 port map(Z1,not S2,O1);
A6 : and3 port map(Z2,S2,O2);
O1 : or2 port map(O1,O2,O);
end arc;

LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity or2 is
port(a,b : in bit;
c : out bit);
end or2;
architecture arc1 of or2 is
begin
c<=a or b;
end arc1;
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity or4 is
port(a,b,c,d : in bit;
e : out bit);
end or4;
architecture arc2 of or4 is
begin
e<=a or b or c or d;
end arc2;
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity and3 is
port(a,b,c : in bit;
d : out bit);
end and3;
architecture arc3 of and3 is
begin
d<=a and b and c;
end arc3;
```

ERROR LOG:

```
# Compile...
# File: c:\Users\Divyanshu\Downloads\HDL\div\mux\src\try.vhd
# Compile Entity "MUX81"
# Entity `MUX81' has been skipped - no difference detected.
# Compile Architecture "struc" of Entity "MUX81"
# Error: ELAB1_0021: try.vhd : (18, 1): Types do not match for port "A".
# Error: ELAB1_0011: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "S" is on entity "mux41" but not on the component declaration.
# Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "B" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
# Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "C" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
# Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "D" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
# Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "S0" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
# Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "S1" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
# Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "Q" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
# Error: COMP96_0122: try.vhd : (21, 1): Symbol "Z1" has already been declared in this region.
# Error: COMP96_0122: try.vhd : (21, 1): Symbol "Z2" has already been declared in this region.
# Error: COMP96_0078: try.vhd : (25, 32): Unknown identifier "O".
# Error: COMP96_0133: try.vhd : (25, 32): Cannot find object declaration.
# Error: COMP96_0104: try.vhd : (25, 32): Undefined type of expression.
# Compile Entity "mux41"
# Entity `mux41' has been skipped - no difference detected.
# Compile Architecture "struc1" of Entity "mux41"
# Error: COMP96_0019: try.vhd : (39, 1): Keyword "end" expected.
# Error: COMP96_0018: try.vhd : (40, 14): Identifier expected.
# Error: COMP96_0019: try.vhd : (42, 1): Keyword "end" expected.
# Error: COMP96_0018: try.vhd : (43, 14): Identifier expected.
# Compile Entity "mux21"
# Entity `mux21' has been skipped - no difference detected.
# Compile Architecture "arc" of Entity "mux21"
# Error: COMP96_0019: try.vhd : (67, 1): Keyword "end" expected.
# Error: COMP96_0018: try.vhd : (68, 14): Identifier expected.
# Error: COMP96_0019: try.vhd : (70, 1): Keyword "end" expected.
# Error: COMP96_0018: try.vhd : (71, 14): Identifier expected.
# Compile Entity "or2"
# Entity `or2' has been skipped - no difference detected.
# Compile Architecture "arc1" of Entity "or2"
# Compile Entity "or4"
# Entity `or4' has been skipped - no difference detected.
# Compile Architecture "arc2" of Entity "or4"
# Compile Entity "and3"
# Entity `and3' has been skipped - no difference detected.
# Compile Architecture "arc3" of Entity "and3"
# Compile failure 21 Errors 0 Warnings  Analysis time :  0.4 [s]
```

I know some errors are very basic but this is my first project on VHDL by myself.
Thanx in Advance.

Comment: For a start, I would suggest that you make small modules and try these out in a simulator.  You can find good examples to tryout under [VHDL/Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl#Further_reading).  Altera has a free edition of ModelSim, called [ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition](http://www.altera.com/products/software/quartus-ii/modelsim/qts-modelsim-index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have a component declaration

```
COMPONENT mux41 is
PORT(A,B,C,D,S0,S1:IN STD_LOGIC;Q:OUT STD_LOGIC);
```

and an entity declaration

```
ENTITY mux41 IS
PORT(
A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
S : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
Z : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END mux41;
```

These are very different. And the error messages tell you exactly what is wrong.

```
Error: ELAB1_0021: try.vhd : (18, 1): Types do not match for port "A".
Error: ELAB1_0011: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "S" is on entity "mux41" but not on the component declaration.
Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "B" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".
Error: ELAB1_0030: try.vhd : (18, 0): Port "C" is on component "mux41" but not on the entity "mux41".`
```

Indeed port A is a std_logic in one, and a std_logic_vector in the other : as the message says, these do not match. And the entity has a port "S" while the component does not. And so on...

Fixing them might involve writing a new entity which matches the component, or editing the component declaration and the port maps to match the entity you already have.

And as Morten and says, catch the basic errors in simulation... if you can't get access to Modelsim, the free Xilinx tools contain a decent simulator (Isim) or there is the open-source tool GHDL.

Answer (score 0):

As MortenZdk says, use a simulator like ModelSim to learn VHDL syntax is better. You can compile a single VHDL file instead of the whole project and run the simulator to veritfy it. And ModelSim is very easy to use for its great online tutorial:).